# Nested QMap and QList won't let me append/push_back

Tags: qt, qlist, qmap

I am trying to utilize a nested QList:

```
QMap<int, QMap<QString, QList<int> > > teamGames;
for (int team1 = 1; team1 <= TOTAL_TEAMS; ++team1) {
    QMap<QString,QList<int>> games;
    teamGames[team1]=games;
    QList<int> home;
    QList<int> away;

    games["home"] = home;
    games["away"] = away;
}

teamGames.value(1).value("home").push_back(1);
```

When I compile I get:
1>.\main.cpp(154) : error C2662: 'QList::push_back' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const QList' to 'QList &'

I'm sure its something simple that I'm overlooking, or maybe there is a simpler solution that's eluding me.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmap.html#value) `QMap::value(const Key & key) const;` returns a `const T`, which means you can not modify what you get. Even if you could you would modify a **copy** of the value you put into the map. What you need is [T& QMap::operator[](const Key& key)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmap.html#operator-5b-5d) which returns the value associated with the key **as a modifiable reference**. So call

```
((teamGames[1])["home"]).push_back(1);
```

Comment: well, maybe i answer too quickly, but as you stated in your answer, `QMap::value()` returns a const-copy-thing, so even for the first call you'll have to use `operator []` this way : `teamGames[1]["home"].push_back(1) ;`. Or am I wrong ?

Comment: @totem I'm afraid you are right! I am going to edit my answer. Thank you!